# Can i make columns of my section in crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i am working in Crystal Reports for VS2010 with asp2.0 .net, can i make the columns of sections, as i have columns of my tables, and i dont want to overlap, as with labels, they overlap some times.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar w/ the VS2010 .net interface, but if it is the GUI, you can set insert tab-stops at the desired spacing.  The fields will "snap" and anchor to the tab-stop line when you move them.  You can shrink/grow each field so that both left and right sides are anchored, constraining that field.  You can then take the next field, and anchor it's left side to the right-side tab-stop from the last field, and repeat.  When you're through, all fields will be nicely constrained, and you can adjust the placement by moving the tab-stop.  The fields will "rubber-band" and grow or shrink w/ the movement of the tab-stops.

This is REALLY good when you need to export to Excel format, and you don't want the CR print engine to include extra lines/columns as it tries to match the "just a little off" layout.

I "think" I need less "air quotes" and more "air guitar".